# ReactJS - create chunks automatically with lazy loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Let's suppose we have three pages and we want to split them into different chunks.That could happen if we manually add `/* webpackChunkName: "chunkName" */`.

```
const Home = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "HomePage" */ "../../pages/Home"));
const Login = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Login" */ "../../pages/Login"));
const Register = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Register" */ "../../pages/Register"));
```

Is it possible to make our lives easier and avoid using webpackChunkName all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `[request]` placeholder in chunk name comment to dynamically set the chunk name.

You can create a function which will call the `import()` function and use `[request]` placeholder to set the dynamic chunk name.

Afterwards, use this function to lazily import components.

Here is one example.

```
const lazyImport = path => {
  return import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `${path}`);
};

const Home = React.lazy(() => lazyImport("../../pages/Home"));
// Chunk name will be pages-Home.chunk.js
```